# Magento htaccess redirection 301

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect, magento-1.7

I am trying to redirect to some  magento urls to http

My current url are

```
https://www.amitbera.com/shop.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/abc.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/abc.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/jde.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg/gyt.html
https://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg/gyt/test.html
```

**I want to redirect all shop url to** `http url` .**Just like mysql function like function** shop% `redirect to 301 https to http`

```
http://www.amitbera.com/shop.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/abc.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/abc.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/jde.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg/gyt.html
http://www.amitbera.com/shop/fg/gyt/test.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this in the Magento Admin panel.

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure

```
Use Secure URL's in Frontend: Yes
```

Set that option to no, and it should redirect to http:// automatically.

Comment: if you didnt make this through the solution as mentioned above there might be a problem i.e., cart and checkout pages will also be redirected through HTTP only. In my consideration this will be a huge reputation loss.

Answer (score 1):

This code for solved this problem

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(shop|blog|stockists|inthepress|contacts|review|home) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

Thanks!!!!!!!!